# How to clone a two-dimensional array of float entries to another two-dimensional array of similar type and size?

Tags: java, arrays, clone, dimension

I hava a problem to clone a two-dimensional array of float entries to another
two-dimensional array of similar type and size. Below is my coding, anyone can help me to check which part I got wrong? Thanks.

```
public class Clone2Darray {
    public static int[][] clone(int[][] a) throws Exception {
        float b[][] = new int[a.length][a[0].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++)
                b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        float a[][]= {{1.513,2.321,3.421},{4.213,5.432,6.123},{7.214,8.213,9.213}};


        try {
            float b[][] = Clone2Darray.clone(a);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(b[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

My coding come out these errors like below:

```
  C:\Users\User-Win7\.netbeans\7.1\var\cache\executor-snippets\run.xml:48: 
  Cancelled by user.
  BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

I want the output like below:

```
  1.513 2.321 3.421
  4.213 5.432 6.123
  7.214 8.213 9.213

  1.513 2.321 3.421
  4.213 5.432 6.123
  7.214 8.213 9.213
```

Comment: So what is your problem, can you put what outcome you have and what is wrong with it?

Comment: You are using `int` arrays everywhere in your `clone` method, those need to be `float` arrays if you want to preserve the type. The current code won't compile this way.

Comment: if you want to clone a float array, why are you using `int[][]` in your clone method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Change method parameter from int to float.

2 - change return type from int to float.

3 - while assign float value in array use f after every number to tell compiler that its a float number.

```
public static float[][] clone(float[][] a) throws Exception {
    float b[][] = new float[a.length][a[0].length];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    return b;
}



    float[][] a = new float[][] { { 1.513f, 2.321f, 3.421f }, { 4.213f, 5.432f, 6.123f },
            { 7.214f, 8.213f, 9.213f } };

    try {
        float b[][] = clone(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(b[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error!!!");
    }
```

Comment: Yup. Output can show me the float. But can't appear clone the array.

Comment: But can't appear clone the array - what do you mean?

Comment: Mean want copy same the array

Comment: It will copy same array. f notation is for compiler. it does not change or impact on any thing.